# How to get database error when i try to delete a row that has its key like foreign key in another table?

Tags: laravel, migration

(Laravel framework)

How to create tables in database with migrations so when I try to delete a row from a table that has its key as a foreign key somewhere in another table, I got an error from database not letting me to do that ?

Do I have to create relations in migrations where I say what are the foreign keys in my database, or is there another way using only Laravel models.

I am new with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove deactivate the foreign key check so to say, I am using following function to accomplish that. First I set the Foreign key check to 0 then truncate the table and set it back to 1. Setting the foreign key check to 0 allows one to truncate the table even if there are foreign keys.

```
# functions to truncate users table even if there are foreign key
public static function truncateUserTable()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
    User::query()->truncate();
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you.

Comment: @SeadOrdagić keep in mind this will keep your data in an inconsistent state of referencing non-existing foreign keys. Don't do this unless you're certain it's what you need

Comment: You can also use `Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();` and `Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();`.

Comment: @apokryfos if he does this for test purpose or something like that its fine I think since it sets to foreign key checks to 1 again